# Issue with .inc file on converting from asp to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic, include

I am converting a asp page to asp.net.In the login page I have got 3 include files

```
<!-- #include file="includes/const.inc" -->    
<!-- #include file="includes/ShiftFuncs.inc" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="includes/xmlutil.asp" -->
```

And in the ShiftFunc.inc there is a set of codes and it also includes another inc files
    <%

```
Option Explicit

Response.AddHeader "Expires", "Fri, Jun 12, 1981 08:20"

Response.AddHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"

Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "No-Cache"

Response.Buffer = True

If IsEmpty( Session("user") ) Then

    Response.Write "<SCRIPT>" & chr(13) & chr(10) & "top.location.href='login.asp'" & chr(13) & chr(10) & "</SCRIPT>" & chr(13) & chr(10)

    Response.Redirect("login.asp")

End If

'Response.Write "User: " & Session("user") & "<BR>" & crlf
%>
<!-- #include file="globals.inc" -->
```

Which is the best way to convert the inc files? Do I need to create a class for this? or just convert these files to aspx pages and then include it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to consist of [http meta tags](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html), controlling the caching of your page, code to check whether a user is logged in or not and references to other files containing constants and utility functions.

The cache control headers could all be easily added to a [Master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX) in the asp.net version of your site.

The user login checks could also be carried out in the Master page, if you're going to reuse the Session("user") method, and any login / user management pages you have, but you might be better off reworking it with something like the [Asp.net membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which could offer you a lot more features and functionality.

The constants contained in globals.inc and const.inc could be duplicated in new vb.net classes, perhaps as [enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx)? And the functions in xmlutil.asp, if they're even still needed in the .net world, I'm sure could reproduced as static methods in a new vb.net class.